# Sidekiq architecture questions

Tags: sidekiq

I want to check that I am not causing an infinite number of workers to be created on heroku.

I have the following job that is started by the clockwork gem on heroku:

```
every 5.minutes, SyncAccounts
```

The Sync Accounts looks like this:

```
  def perform
    UserRepo.all.each do |user|
      EnqueueFolderSyncJobs.perform_async user.id
      SyncContacts.perform_async user.id
      SyncMeetings.perform_async user.id
    end
  end
```

It iterates through every user and creates further workers.  Each of these workers might create more workers, for example, EnqueFolderSyncJobs creates a worker to sync imap folders:

```
  google.email.folders.each do |folder|
    SyncFolder.perform_async user_id, folder unless skip?(folder)
  end
```

So every 5 minutes this is happening.

Does calling perform_async mean that the job only happens once?

Do I need call drain at the end of all this?

Also, all the workers are being created under the same queue, should I create separate queues for SyncFolders for example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sidekiq by default limits concurrency to 25 workers. You can increase that in your sidekiq.yml if need be. But that concurrency is what limits it from "infinite" workers. https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Advanced-Options#concurrency

Calling "perform_async" means you are calling that job once, it would only occur again if it failed and was retried. I see no reason for you to create another queue, unless some jobs take precedence and should always be processed first. https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Advanced-Options#queues

Calling .drain is unnecessary except in test environments.

If you absolutely want your workers to be processed in a certain workflow, instead of having all your jobs dumped into the queue at once (in your example, it doesn't look important), take a look at Sidekiq Superworker. I haven't used it myself but it looks interesting.

https://github.com/socialpandas/sidekiq-superworker